# manipulate mousedown object on drop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I'm trying to change the object that drops when it activates with mousedown. For example:

I have a list with `<a>` tags, when I'm dragging it to a textarea and drops it. I get the url as a string. But I don't want the full url when I'm dropping it (I want a part of it).

href in a-tag look like this: **?page=1** but when I drop it in the textarea I see **http://localhost/page.php?page=1**

So is it possible to change the outcome of the object when dropping it in the textarea?

**Edit:**

Current jQuery code:

```
jQuery("ul.editpages a").mousedown(function(object){
    newobject = object.srcElement.innerText;
});
```

Current HTML:

```
<ul class='editpages'>
    <li><a href="?page=1"><span>Page 1</span></a></li>
</ul>
<textarea class='redactor'>
</textarea>
```

I'm trying to use the native drag and drop which all modern browsers provide because then I can insert the content att a point in the text, rather than in a position (as jquery droppable and draggable do)

Comment: Could we have your code please, are you using jquery draggable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is interested:

In Google chrome the problem was that I thought it would change on the drop. That didn't work. It couldn't find anything in the object when I dropped it. So I changed focus to the things I was trying to drag.

So on `<a>` I added `draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"`

This is the drag-function.

```
function drag(ev){
    fullurl = ev.target.href;
    shorturl = fullurl.substring(fullurl.indexOf('?')).replace("?page=", "");
    tag = "<PAGE page='"+shorturl+"'>"
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",tag);
}
```

When I now drag it, it will show up as a formatted string in the textarea.

This won't work properly in Opera (according to http://help.dottoro.com/ljmpcqdb.php), but since no one has visited our site.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do something with the javascript onDrop event

```
<textarea class='redactor' ondrop="myfunction()">
```

And change the content of the textarea with a substring of the href

Comment: Worked perfectly! Never thought of that